# Unable to record my call in Android 4.4

Tags: android, call, android-mediarecorder

I am not able to record my call in **Android 4.4**. I checked few applications from GooglePlay but they don't work properly either.

In my application I use `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL` but that doesn't work.

Anyone knows the solution?

Answer (score 0):

See the link -

[Audiosource-voice-call-not-working-in-android-4-0-but-working-in-android-2-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14728615/audiosource-voice-call-not-working-in-android-4-0-but-working-in-android-2-3/14785968#14785968)

> After a lot of search I Found that Some Manufactures have closed the
>   access to such function because call recording is not allowed in some
>   countries. If anyone finds such question and get the solution some
>   other way then post it over here it may be helpful to many because
>   many people are have the same issue.