# Move an application to the Accessibility Applications page

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, accessibilityservice

I want to access the accessibility page for an application to help with ease of use

```
val intent = Intent("android.settings.ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS") 
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically enabling/disabling accessibility settings on Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38360198/programmatically-enabling-disabling-accessibility-settings-on-android-device)