# java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)

Tags: android, android-studio, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I am working on records a phone calls. When i start a record a phone call then it's unfortunately stop. & it's gives error MediaRecorder start fail -2147483648. I Please tell me what is the problem in my code? Here is my Code.

```
public class incomingcall extends BroadcastReceiver {
Context c;
MediaRecorder recorder;
public incomingcall() {
}
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    c = context;
    try {
        PhoneStateChangeListener pscl = new PhoneStateChangeListener();
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        tm.listen(pscl, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("", "", e);
    }
}

private class PhoneStateChangeListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                Toast.makeText(c, "ring", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                startRecording();
                Toast.makeText(c, "offhook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                stopRecording();
                Toast.makeText(c, "idle", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
}
private void startRecording() {
    try {
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        String file=c.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
        file+="/sound.3gp";
        recorder.setOutputFile(file);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("", "prepare() failed", e);
    }
}
private void stopRecording() {
    try {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
        recorder = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("", "", e);
    }
 }
}
```

Log

```
    07-20 15:33:47.867 18525-18525/in.pounkumar.callblocker E/MediaRecorder: start failed: -2147483648
07-20 15:33:47.868 18525-18525/in.pounkumar.callblocker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: in.pounkumar.callblocker, PID: 18525
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
                                                                              at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
                                                                              at in.pounkumar.callblocker.incomingcall.startRecording(incomingcall.java:73)
                                                                              at in.pounkumar.callblocker.incomingcall.access$100(incomingcall.java:20)
                                                                              at in.pounkumar.callblocker.incomingcall$PhoneStateChangeListener.onCallStateChanged(incomingcall.java:53)
                                                                              at android.telephony.PhoneStateListener$2.handleMessage(PhoneStateListener.java:295)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: do you've permissions to record audio in your manifest file?

Comment: ya ,     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
 i already added this

Comment: @PounKumarPurushothaman your android OS version is 6.0?

Comment: you have to get runtime permissions from user otherwise cant do it.  look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38141523/directory-creation-not-working-in-marshmallow-android/38141778#38141778

Comment: already added bro @SohailZahid

Comment: @PounKumarPurushothaman have you added this <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT" /> while getting permission from user. if you added it later unistall app and then install again

Comment: no changes bro @SohailZahid

Comment: I'm having same issue. Let me know If you got any solution for this.

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem and i solved it by using different initializations for Samsung and LG devices.

```
        String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
    if (manufacturer.toLowerCase().contains("samsung")) {
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
    } else {
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
    }
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you! I was going to disappoint about running my app on Samsung phones. How did you find this? Can you provide any link to a document about this?

Comment: By trial and error. Notice, Android 7 blocks these options.

Comment: which option you mean? I tried this on Samsung Note 6 using Android 7 and it worked!

Comment: But it doesn't record second person voice. Tried it in my Galaxy S8+ running Android 7.0

Comment: Android 7 blocks the ability to record the other side of the call due to privacy violence issues.

Answer (score 0):

MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL source requires the CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT permission. [**See Android Docs**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT)

Have you added this permission in your manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT" />
```

Comment: @PounKumarPurushothaman which permission you have added in manifest?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT"/><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

Comment: can use paste all permission here. and any change in logcat after adding this permission.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT"/><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

Comment: My application was working since months, suddenly it realised that it should not work without this permission, I had to add this and it started working. I am not kidding. As days pass by I am starting to believe that code rots if you don't touch it for some time. :(

Answer (score -1):

The `MediaRecorder.start` method fails in your case, due to this :

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
```

The reason why `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL` source doesn't work depends on your device manufacturer/country etc.

So, this is throwing an exception as `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL` is **NOT** supported on your device.

Try changing it to `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC` and it will work :

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139332/voice-call-recording-in-android-using-mediarecorder) for more details.

Comment: try using `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER`

Comment: Android 7 blocks the ability to record the other side of the call due to privacy violence issues.