# AudioSource.VOICE_CALL not working in android 6.0 version

Tags: android

Run time `exception` in

```
                recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
                recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL flg=0x10000010 (has
>   extras) } in a.callrecoder.TService$a@e5c022
>                                                                      at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:1138)
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6184)
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:788)
>                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
>                                                                      at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
>                                                                      at a.callrecoder.TService$a.onReceive(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:1128)
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6184) 
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

Comment: change setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL) TO setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC) . It will work on android 6.0 and above. Make sure all permission's are allowed.

Comment: but i want to record downlink not mic voice
MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC record only my voice

Comment: which device are you testing it

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14785968/5110595)

Comment: mi redmi 4 is the device and android version is 7.0.1

Comment: hemant this is not working for record only my voice

Answer (score 0):

The `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL` source requires [`CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT) permission which will be granted just for system apps and NOT for 3rd-party applications.

Comment: Perfect! Then how 3rd party apps are successful in recording caller and callie voice?

Comment: They use NDK and cpp codes for that. please check the url: https://github.com/ViktorDegtyarev/CallRecLib

Comment: Did you use that library? Please see the issues of that first.