# MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL is not working for call Recording in Android 4.1.2

Tags: android, mediarecorder

https://github.com/esnyder/callrecorder
 I've applied this source code to perform call recording but It's not recording call (Two Way Recording).

After searching a lot I've got android have banned call recording service after version 4.1. But there is an [CallRecorder App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=polis.app.callrecorder) on google play which is working fine in my mobile too.

How can I perform call recording feature in my app?

Comment: _"android have banned call recording service after version 4.1"_ Do you have an official quote for that? I see nothing on this subject in the Android 4.3 Compatibility Definition Document; nor have I heard a word about this during the years when I was working professionally with Android audio HAL customizations.

Comment: @Michael Is there any Method to perform call recording... If it's been banned then It should not work in this app too [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=polis.app.callrecorder) but it is working here.

Comment: The proper way of recording voice call audio is simply to use the `VOICE_CALL` AudioSource. Note that Google doesn't implement the voice call recording functionality, because it's platform specific. So whether or not it works on a specific device depends on whether the platform vendor and/or OEM has implemented that feature.

Comment: @Michael I m also using VOICE_CALL AudioSource but it's not working in my mobile SONY XPERIA J.... I've download an app 'Call Recorder' which is working in my device too

Comment: I'm not familiar with the XPeria J, but it appears to be a budget model, considering that it was released in 2012 but using platform from 2009-2010. I remember that the MSM7227 (the platform in question) originally had a limitation that only allowed you to record the downlink voice call audio (the audio coming from the other party), and only in AMR format. It's possible that it still had the same limitation when the Xperia J was released. It's also possible that they removed the voice call recording support altogether on this product because of that limitation.

Answer (score 2):

[AudioSource.VOICE_CALL not working in android 4.0 but working in android 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14728615/audiosource-voice-call-not-working-in-android-4-0-but-working-in-android-2-3/14785968#14785968)

posting late on thread but still Check this link hope it will help 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rivalogic.android.callrecorder&hl=en